# How do you set JAVA_OPTS for a service based version of tomcat using plesk on linux?

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, tomcat5.5

I have installed a servlet (solr) that requires that I set the variable `solr.solr.home` equal to solr home. Something like:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-D=solr.solr.home='/usr/share/tomcat/solr'
```

The version of tomcat I am using is running as a service setup through plesk control panel. After googling this I found a page that said I should edit the web.xml file in the war file and then re-jar it. I uncommented a section in the web.xml and filled in the necessary fields:

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-value>/usr/share/tomcat5/solr</env-entry-value>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

I repackaged the war file and reinstalled through the control panel but the logs are still complaining that solr/home needs to be set.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this can be found at this question:
[Why can't solr 1.3.0 install using CentOS, plesk 9.2.1 and tomcat 5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280548/why-cant-solr-1-3-0-install-using-centos-plesk-9-2-1-and-tomcat-5-5)

Also, what I was doing in the web.xml file WAS correct. The tomcat logs were complaining aobut solr/home NOT being set but that wasn't the actual problem. Tomcat was missing a reference to the xalan library, and I explain in the link above how I went about fixing it.